# Flask - Generated PDF can be viewed but cannot be downloaded

Tags: flask, pythonanywhere

I recently started learning flask and created a simple webapp which randomly generates kids' math work sheets in PDF based on user input.

The PDF opens automatically in a browser and can be viewed. But when I try downloading it both on a PC and in Chrome iOS, I get error messages (Chrome PC: Failed - Network error / Chrome iOS:the file could not be downloaded at this time).

You can try it out here: `kidsmathsheets.com`

I suspect it has something to do with the way I'm generating and returning the PDF file. FYI I'm using ReportLab to generate the PDF. My code below (hosted on pythonanywhere):

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4, letter
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.platypus import Table
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, Response
import io
from werkzeug import FileWrapper

# Other code to take in input and generate data

    filename=io.BytesIO()

    if letter_size:
        c = canvas.Canvas(filename, pagesize=letter)
else:
    c = canvas.Canvas(filename, pagesize=A4)

pdf_all(c, p_set, answer=answers, letter=letter_size)
c.save()
filename.seek(0)
wrapped_file = FileWrapper(filename)

return Response(wrapped_file, mimetype="application/pdf", direct_passthrough=True)

else:
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Any idea what's causing the issue? Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using [`send_file`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.send_file)?

Comment: Yes I've tried send_file() and got the same error messages...

Comment: I believe this may have something to do with Chrome security settings: https://windowsreport.com/failed-network-error-download-chrome/. I tried the PDF download in Firefox and it worked, but it failed for me in the same way in Chrome (on linux)

Comment: Thanks Glenn. I have a windows machine and it's failing on Microsoft Edge too. So I think there's something wrong with the way I'm delivering the PDF which is causing such errors. Normally if the PDF can be displayed, downloading it should be straight forward...

Comment: Isn't Edge based on Chrome these days?

Comment: But still, shouldn't Chrome be able to download PDF files by default? So there's gotta be something wrong with what I'm doing with my code...?

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you are using an ajax POST request for invoking the endpoint to generate your data and display the PDF respectively. If this is the case - quite probably this causes the behaviour our observe. You might want to try invoking the endpoint with a GET request to `/my-endpoint/some-hashed-non-reusable-id-of-my-document` where `some-hashed-non-reusable-id-of-my-document`will tell the endpoint which document to serve without allowing users to play around with guesstimates about what other documents you might have. You might try it first like:

```
@app.route('/display-document/<document_id>'):
def display_document(document_id):
    document = get_my_document_from_wherever_it_is(document_id)
    binary = get_binary_data_from_document(document)
    .........
    
    Prepare response here
    .......
    return send_file(binary, mimetype="application/pdf")
```

Kind note: a right click and 'print to pdf' will work but this is not the solution we want